# JSON Filter return null

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, array-filter

I´m trying to filter JSON array in Angular like this

JSON

```
1 46 3 2 48 4
```

FILTER

```
   var test = this.users.filter(element => {
            element.id === 1;
          });
```

The problem is 'test' variable return null in every cases. As we can see the 'id' 1 exist, so theoretically should return data. ¿Anybody know what is wrong in this code?

**UPDATE**

Full JSON response

```
  {id: 1, usuario: "alara", nombre: "alara", password: null, apellidos: "alara", …}
  {id: 46, usuario: "ale", nombre: "ale", password: null, apellidos: "ale", …}
  {id: 3, usuario: "jorge", nombre: "jorge", password: null, apellidos: null, …}
  {id: 2, usuario: "apple", nombre: "apple", password: null, apellidos: null, …}
  {id: 48, usuario: "arsontech", nombre: "arsontech", password: null, apellidos: null, …}
  {id: 47, usuario: "Pedro", nombre: "pedro", password: null, apellidos: "Bilbao", …}
```

Comment: You sure it's not just `element === 1`? What does the `users` object look like?

Comment: Update with the full JSON response.

Comment: I took the liberty of arranging your tags to target the correct communities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var test = this.users.filter(element => {
        element.id === 1;
      });
```

You don't return anything.

```
var test = this.users.filter(element => element.id === 1);
```

Should work better. Or you can also use this :

```
var test = this.users.filter(element => {
  return element.id === 1;
});
```